# Maven: no marketplace entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.5

Tags: java, selenium, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

Noob here. Downloaded a repo from a past and forgotten project to try to relearn automation but I'm stuck with this error. I tried updating maven project but still can't come up with a solution. Hope you guys can help.

I feel like there is a somewhere pretty easy solution to this but I'm a noob and I'm stuck with the error for half a day so maybe posting here might help. Thanks

[Actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqe7K.png)

[Plugin error in pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxD1P.png)

[Pom error line 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgeBC.png)

whole pom:

```
<project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spwr.testautomation.partnerportal.qa</groupId>
  <artifactId>spwr-testautomation-partnerportal-qa</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
        <maven.compile.encoding>UTF-8</maven.compile.encoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.9.0</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>  
  </properties>
   
  <dependencies>
      
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
   
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>15.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.ashot/ashot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
    <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
                
  </dependencies>  
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.5</version>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                            <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports/</outputDirectory>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <jsonFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>**/*.json</param>
                            </jsonFiles>
                            <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                            <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                            <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                            <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                            <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                            <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                            <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
        </plugin>
        
    </plugins>
  </build> 
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is simply that a version 3.8.5 of the maven-compiler-plugin does not exist...you can select a versions

- 3.8.1
- 3.9.0
- 3.10.0
- 3.10.1

You can search in central repository like this:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin

Furthermore you should check your builds first on plain command line.

An overview of the currently existing plugins and version can be found here:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: I would assume the base problem is to understand that Apache Maven and the maven-compile-plugin are two distinct things (3.8.5 sounds to me like the Apache Maven version number).

Comment: Here the issue is the version of maven-compiler-plugin ...